# npm run dev returns "Failed: EOF" error on DigitalOcean Apps

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, digital-ocean

I am working to migrate a Laravel web application to DigitalOcean's new App platform. We have been running this application on several machines over the past few months with no npm issues. However, now we are encountering the below error when we attempt to run `npm run dev` on the new machine. Can any help in diagnosing or resolving this issue?

Below is the output of the command line after running `npm run dev`. I have never encountered an error like this before.

```
> @ dev /workspace
> npm run development


> @ development /workspace
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

14% building 36/37 modules 1 active ...?ref--5-2!/workspace/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??postcss0!/workspace/resources/css/app.csswaiting on pid 280: waiting on PID 280 in sandbox "36e292c375c65ecbc35b98c3e6d84847ea4a0f86a3fcadaf6119ab9202d9c0db": urpc method "containerManager.WaitPID" failed: EOF
```

Comment: Any solution bro @Weston Burchett

Comment: Same error here! Did you solve it?

Comment: add more mem to your platform @Weston Burchett & check [this](https://docs.digitalocean.com/support/when-connecting-to-redis-i-get-an-endoffile-error/)